# Get mysqldump debug information

Tags: php, file-io, exec, mysql

I currently have a PHP ChronJob that makes a daily backup of my database, and the script is as follows:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(86000);
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pagetop.php");
$db = new dbsettings;
$filename = date("d-m-Y");
$output = array();
$output =  shell_exec("C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=".$db->username." --password=".$db->password." --host=".$db->hostname." --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --skip-extended-insert --disable-keys --add-locks --force --debug-info ".$db->databaseName." > ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."backups/".$filename.".sql");
//Write backup log
$file = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."backups/backup.log", "a");
fwrite($file, "\n\r".print_r($output, true)."\n\r");
fclose($file);
?>
```

It all works perfectly, creating an SQL file in the correct format, but I cannot for the life of me write the debug information to a log, even though I have the `--debug-info` argument which:

> Print debugging information and memory and CPU usage statistics when
>   the program exits.

How do I correctly write this information to a file?

Comment: --debug[=debug_options], -# [debug_options]

Write a debugging log. A typical debug_options string is 'd:t:o,file_name'. The default value is 'd:t:o,/tmp/mysqldump.trace'.

Comment: @RobertRozas I just tried that, and I get `mysqldump: ERROR: Option 'debug='d:t:o,/backups/mysqldump.trace'' used, but is disabled` in the Apache error log

Comment: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-apache-httpd-access-and-error-log/

Comment: Why will that solve anything?! I'll get even less information about what's going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option simply does not seem to be working on Windows. I am not surprised, because these informations are less readily available on this system than on Linux, and the MySQL folks perhaps didn't bother porting this little used option.

On Linux, the debug information is sent to `stderr` (you would typically capture this info with a `2>debug.log` redirection).

Comment: I'll leave this open for a while, just in case someone does have a solution. But I think the fact that absolutely nothing happens, there's no error messages; like it's just being ignored would lead me to think you are correct!